# Can I mount Azure Files Storage from my local Workstation?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-files

I want to mount Azure Files Storage to my local Workstation.
The documentation seems not to be clear at this point.

The note from documentation

> Some Internet service providers may block port 445

seems to prove this szenario, but the `net use` doens't work localy (Azure VM works fine).

I get this Error:

> “The network name cannot be found”

Documentation: https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files.md#mount-the-file-share-from-an-on-premises-client-running-windows

Edit:

- Local Workstation runs with Windows 10 Pro
- Command was `net use <drive-letter>: \\<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net\<share-name> /u:<storage-account-name> <storage-account-key>` It works from an Azure instance in the same region and subscription.

Edit 2:

It works, but only one time! After a reboot i ran into the same problem.
A TCP Ping against the SMB Port succed only the azure vm.

Local Workstation

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName SHARENAME.file.core.windows.net -Port 445
TcpTestSucceeded       : False
```

Azure VM

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName SHARENAME.file.core.windows.net -Port 445
TcpTestSucceeded       : True
```

It seems, that my ISP is blocking port 445.

Comment: This should work. Can you share 2 things - 1) OS you're using 2) Full `net use` command you used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously your mileage may vary, but this works fine for me

I use the following Powershell script

```
$pass = "password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
                          -argumentlist "topbanananas",$pass

New-PSDrive -Name p -PSProvider FileSystem `
            -Root \\topbanananas.file.core.windows.net\fruity `
            -Credential $credentials -Persist
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using Comcast (aka xfinity) as my ISP and port 445 is blocked.  So I can't map a drive letter from windows 10 using the normal simple method.  However, I accidentally got it to work using this procedure:

1) Created a ubuntu 16.04 server VM in Azure using the minimum size allowed by Azure (this is very cheap to run)

2) Installed OpenVPN server on the ubuntu server and OpenVPN client on Windows 10.  For the procedure, search for "How To Set Up an OpenVPN Server on Ubuntu 16.04".

3) Connected to the VPN

4) The windows drive letter now maps fine.

I'm not saying this is a good solution, or an easy solution.  It takes a lot of time to get the OpenVPN server up and running.  I'm sure there must be a better way.  But, I needed the OpenVPN server for another reason anyway.  So it's an OK solution for me until a better solution is found.